# How to reorder sequence number of a table in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting

I've an Angular8 app in which one component is having a primeng table with below data, each row is having a sequence number column

```
tableData = [{id:1465,seqNum:1,name:Maths,desc:Mathematics},{id:1466,seqNum:2,name:Eng,desc:English},{id:1467,seqNum:3,name:Bio,desc:Biology},{id:1468,seqNum:4,name:Chem,desc:Chemistry},{id:1469,seqNum:5,name:Phys,desc:Physics}]
```

I want to update any sequence number to a particular sequence number in the list so that the sequence number in between those two values also updated accordingly.

for example, initial table data will be like below

```
tableData = [{id:1465,seqNum:1,name:Maths,desc:Mathematics},{id:1466,seqNum:2,name:Eng,desc:English},{id:1467,seqNum:3,name:Bio,desc:Biology},{id:1468,seqNum:4,name:Chem,desc:Chemistry},{id:1469,seqNum:5,name:Phys,desc:Physics}]
```

If I change the seqNum:2 to 5, then the table should be updated like below

```
tableData = [{id:1465,seqNum:1,name:Maths,desc:Mathematics},{id:1469,seqNum:2,name:Phys,desc:Physics}{id:1466,seqNum:3,name:Eng,desc:English},{id:1467,seqNum:4,name:Bio,desc:Biology},{id:1468,seqNum:5,name:Chem,desc:Chemistry}]
```

basically I want to reorder the sequence number field of each row in between the selected row. in our example sequence number of rows 2 to 5 should be updated accordingly.

I have the below function on blur of the seqNum column, inside that I'll get the selected row and entire table data

```
updateSeqNbr(selectedRow) { //selectedRow = {id:1466,seqNum:2,name:Eng,desc:English}
this.tableData; //tableData = [{id:1465,seqNum:1,name:Maths,desc:Mathematics}{id:1466,seqNum:2,name:Eng,desc:English},{id:1467,seqNum:3,name:Bio,desc:Biology}, {id:1468,seqNum:4,name:Chem,desc:Chemistry},{id:1469,seqNum:5,name:Phys,desc:Physics}]

// logic

}
```

how to get the updated tableData with sequence number change?

Comment: Looks like to be swapping array elements by their respective positions. Also, you will have to change the `seqNum` specifically.

Comment: Create a pipe to sort your data: https://angular.io/guide/pipes